# SonarQube unable to understand Java inline expression for null check

Tags: java, sonarqube

We are doing static code analysis using SonarQube. 
We are facing following Bug found by SonarQube

```
NullPointerException might be thrown as 'evt' is nullable here
```

in following code

```
try {
//business logic

}(Exception e){
    throw new MyException("Found issue for event " + evt.getDeatil());
}
```

So to remove this bug we have introduced small inline code for null check

```
try {
//business logic

 }(Exception e){
     throw new MyException("Found issue for event " + evt != null ?
       evt.getDeatil() : null);
}
```

Still SonarQube showing same violation bug after code change.

Could anyone please help us to find what we are missing here?

Comment: What is the version of SonarJava installed on your SonarQube server ?

Comment: SonarJava version is 3.X

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in line:

```
throw new MyException("Found issue for event " + evt != null ? evt.getDeatil() : null);
```

The problem is [operators precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). `+` is evaluated before `?:` so your code is equal to:

```
String message = "Found issue for event " + evt;
throw new MyException(message != null ? evt.getDeatil() : null);
```

NullPointerException still can occur. Additional you've introduced a new problem - expression:

```
message != null
```

always evaluates to `true`.

To fix it you have to add curly brackets:

```
throw new MyException("Found issue for event " + (evt != null ? evt.getDeatil() : null));
```